# UI5 - use url parameter for displaying text

Tags: datatable, odata, sapui5, northwind

I am trying to build a table using the [NorthWind - oData Service.](https://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata) where first column shows the `customerIds` and second column shows the `companyNames`.

Third column should display the count of orders of each company.
I would like to access the count using [NorthWind - $count URL parameter](https://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers('ANATR')/Orders/$count).

That's not working, because the text attribute of the Text UI5 component doesn't seem support something like this:

```
<Text text="{Orders/$count}"/>
```

Could you help me out?

I already tried with a custom formatter, counting the arrays length and of course that's working. but I want to try to display the count without the need for a custom function. just using the `$count` parameter would be nice.

Comment: OData V3 is not supported by UI5

Answer (score 2):

In V4 its quite simple, https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/77d2310b637b490495d78b393ed6aa64

```
<Table id="SalesOrders"
    items="{
        path : '/SalesOrderList',
        parameters : {
            $count : true,
        }
    }"
>
    <headerToolbar>
        <Toolbar>
            <content>
                <Title id="SalesOrdersTitle" text="{$count} Sales Orders"/>
            </content>
        </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
    ...
</Table>
```

Comment: thanks vor helping me out there. i have no experience with v4 services. just changing the url would not suffice i guess. what do i have to change in the manifest to make it work? :)